# Null values aren't counted when joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have two tables, called `vservers` and `nodes`:

`vservers`:

```
vserverid **PK** | nodeid **FK** 
1              5
2              6
3              7
```

`nodes`:

```
nodeid | name     | maxvps
5       some_name    4
6       some_name    4
7       some_name    4
```

So if there are some `vservers` which has no values, they won't be count or fetched via PHP.

```
SELECT nodes.name as name, COUNT(vservers.vserverid) as count_vps ,nodes.maxvps
FROM nodes, vservers
WHERE vservers.nodeid = nodes.nodeid
AND nodes.name LIKE 'some_name%'
GROUP BY name
```

My second approach was this as well, but it returns the same result:

```
SELECT nodes.name as name, COUNT(*)- COUNT(vservers.vserverid) as count_vps, nodes.maxvps
FROM nodes, vservers
WHERE vservers.nodeid = nodes.nodeid
AND nodes.name LIKE 'some_name%'
GROUP BY name
```

but still it gives the same result - null values aren't included.
EDIT:
So far, I've figured that NULL values aren't count. So there is a function ISNULL that counts both NULL and real values. Problem is that I don't know how to implement it.

Any suggestion guys?

Comment: you're doing an inner join. you need to use a left/right join instead. inner join = records MUST exist in both tables in the join. left/right - records must exist in ONE of the tables, but not necessarily in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT nodes.name as name, COUNT(vservers.vserverid) as count_vps ,nodes.maxvps
FROM vservers
LEFT JOIN nodes ON(vservers.nodeid = nodes.nodeid AND nodes.name LIKE 'some_name%')
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both LEFT and RIGHT join return an empty result set.

Comment: I just noticed that the `WHERE` condition also refers to `nodes` so that too should go in the `ON` clause. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Still NULL values aren't counted @VoteyDisciple

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

```
SELECT nodes.name, COUNT(vservers.vserverid) AS max_vps 
FROM vservers
RIGHT OUTER JOIN nodes 
ON vservers.nodeid = nodes.nodeid 
WHERE nodes.name LIKE "node_name%" 
GROUP BY name
```

Now those with 0 values are included as well. Thank you all. :)